# Deploy a web project in Myeclipse

Tags: tomcat, myeclipse

I created a new web project,and deployed it in the tomcat 6.0 in Myeclipse,but it showed"An existing resource has been found at location D:\Tomcat\webapps\my_project",what's the problem?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frederick,

MyEclipse is trying to deploy your project to a location which already contains a deployment, one which has not been created with MyEclipse which is why you are being warned. Typically you should also get a few options on how MyEclipse should handle this (delete or create a backup, for instance) - do you not see these options?

If you need further assistance, can you please create a post on the MyEclipse forums here? 
http://myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=PNphpBB2

Please mention the version of MyEclipse you are using.

Thanks,
Brian.

Comment: I set the location D:\Tomcat\webapps as the myeclipse workspace,so it will always warn that an existing resource has been found.Thanks for your help!

Comment: @XiaodanMao I just deleted ALL my files under /home/hguilarte at work thanks to this `few options on how MyEclipse should handle this (delete or create a backup, for instance)`... Well, I made a mistake and didn't choose MyEclipse proper option, however I feel that MyEclipse has a bit of responsibility here too. I was deploying a production packaged WAR, so there was no reason for it to delete EVERYTHING on the destination directory. I'm really screwed at work right now.